# Surface for non-surface applications

Tags: wpf, pixelsense

Recently I've stumbled over surface. It's incredible and so easy to develop small applications with surface. Surface is build upon WPF, so surface uses XAML. My idea is now to develop applications with surface. I've searched  for some information about this topic. There is nothing about that. My question is now, why nobody uses the surface SDK with WPF to build cool applications. Are there any disadvantages?

Comment: MS Surface approximately costs 10k$, it has low market share. With WPF it is also difficult, bacause displays are vertical. Wait for the future when everything will be at low price.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really understand your question. But here are some answers to what you may be asking:

**Why aren't there more surface applications out there?**

Most likely because of the price and the availability. It costs $15,000 for a developer unit and you have to be a business to even get to order it.

**Why isn't the surface SDK used to build normal desktop apps**

Because it doesn't make sense. The surface SDK contains Surface specific, and multi touch specific additions to the plain WPF stack so it is only useful for surface applications running on a real surface device (or simulator, but that isn't feasible for deployment)

Now if you are building a multi touch application for windows 7, there is a [surface toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee957351.aspx) which is based upon the surface SDK. It has most of the nice multi touch enhancements but lacks the hard dependency on the surface hardware. It is very useful for general purpose multi touch development on .NET and is as far as I can tell also used quite much for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean building Windows applications in WPF using the Surface toolkit?  There is no reason not to do this.  There is a 'good, better, best' model when developing multitouch apps, and if you want to create a true multitouch friendly application, then the Surface toolkit is a good way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an application using the surface toolkit but for normal wpf application.
You have just to have a multitouc tactil monitor.
and every thing will be fine.
It works :)